# Websocket write doesn't fail even if the network connection is broken

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have a websocket connection to another server in a different network and I keep sending data to it using the gorilla websocket lib's `WriteMessage` method.
https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/main/conn.go#L768

But when the network connection is broken, say the route is lost, this method doesn't report any error and the data is lost quietly. Is there a way to address this issue?

Comment: Aside from the tcp issue, there are the layers of buffering between your websocket and the actual tcp connection to contend with.

Comment: thanks @JimB. In my observation, the `WriteMessage` method kept returning success though I couldn't see that these are being sent/retransmitted at the TCP layer. Does this indicate that the packets were never written to TCP tx buffer? And after a while, the `WriteMessage` method got blocked and eventually failed once the `WriteDeadline` elapsed. What made it get blocked at this point, the WS/TCP buffer got full?

Comment: @JimB, one more question, when the connection is alright, I see the message getting flushed to the wire immediately as I see from tcpdump. But when the connection fails, it appears that it doesn't get flushed even to the TCP buffers as I couldn't see these on the tcpdump. Why should this be different?

Comment: yes, maybe? We can't tell without instrumenting everything you were doing on your system. You are writing to a buffer, which in turn may be writing to a lower-level buffer, which is asynchronously batching and sending data along the stream. The TCP protocol has a window which it fills while waiting for ACKs that causes backpressure on the system, which can cause different layers to block. It's just the nature of a TCP stream that you can't get immediate feedback by sending data; you can't even be certain the data will be received without acknowledgment from the remote system.

Comment: @JimB, but shouldn't TCP be trying to retransmit the data from its buffer while waiting for ACKs? I don't see even a single TX

Comment: again, maybe? but we can't say without tracing _everything_ that's happening. It might be an interesting learning experience to debug this all the way down the stack; but because you can't count on immediate feedback from network writes in general, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong from the point of view of the websocket write.